# read mysql table columns via ZEND

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db, zend-framework3

I want to validate the columns of an imported excel file with the columns of a template. The template is just a table in my mySQL database.

First I just tried to read the columns of the mySQL table. I used the following code(part of it):

```
$getcol =  PDO::query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM temp");

    while ($row = PDOStatement::fetch($getcol)) {
        echo $row['column_name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Only I just would like to use the database connection I already have. It is my first try with Zend_Framework3 I'm still suffering a bit with this tableadapter stuff. I can use it, but I didn't get all advantages of it.

So my question is, is it possible to read automatically the columns of a mySQL table via Zend? I don't want to have a static tableadapter, because the template could change and then I'd like to just add the new columns  to the temp table in the database and my code does the rest.

Comment: I found a class for ZF2 Zend\Db\Metadata, unfortuantely it is deprecated in Version 3, but I couldn't find a new one wether in the migration guide nor somewhere else.

Comment: Have you looked at using an ORM? Most zend projects use Doctrine2 to manage the datastore

Comment: My intention to ask was, to find a Zend way. I didn't. So I also use phpspreadsheet, and now I read the first row of a template file and compare each of them with the columns in my import file.